# How to restart decorator on error in python

Tags: python, attributeerror, python-decorators, try-except

I have a func() decorator, sometimes it throws an error when running AttributeError, but if you re-run the decorator, then everything works, I tried to fix it through try except, when an error is thrown 1 time, everything works, but if the error is thrown several times, then except doesn't work

````
    try:
        func()
    except AttributeError:
        print('Error login, try again')
        func() ```
````

Comment: This looks like an X-Y problem. You should not have a decorator which catches an `AttributeError` and retries the same call until it succeeds. In fact, you should not have a function which sometimes throws an `AttributeError` and sometimes not, given the same arguments. Solve the cause of the exception instead.

Comment: I have authorization on the site, and sometimes it is blocked and an error occurs, I can’t exclude it in any way

Comment: An authorisation issue should not raise an `AttributeError`. That is a bug. It also should not be retried infinitely. But that's just my opinion, you do what you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while True:
    try:
        func()
        break
    except AttributeError:
        print('Error login, try again')
```

Comment: inside func() i have an entry in sqlite3.connect db and while executing your solution, there is this error: sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error

Comment: @krya That has nothing to do with the Python code above.  Open a new question about the DB connection / query.